# Existence and uniqueness of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

$y'=y+e^{-2t}y^2$

I know the solution is $y=\frac{1}{e^{-2t}+ce^{-t}}$, c constant.

Then the problem says that $y=0$ is a different solution. How can I explain that this doesn't contradict existence and uniqueness of solutions to first-order equations. Is it because it doesn't have an initial condition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's essentially right. For a first-order ODE $y' = F(y, t)$ for a nice function $F$ (here nice means Lipschitz continuous and with open domain), and an initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$ (for which $(y_0, t_0) \in \text{dom}\, F$), there is a solution $y$ of the ODE satisfying the initial condition on some time interval $(a, b)$ containing $t_0$, and any two such solutions agree on the overlap.

In your example, the first solution satisfies the initial condition $y(0) = \frac{1}{c}$ (note that this is actually an entire family of solutions, one for each constant value of $c$). The solution $y(t) = 0$ satisfies $y(0) = 0$, but this initial value cannot be written as $\frac{1}{c}$ for any $c$, so there is no contradiction.